# When a meeting comes to end and you want to conclude from it

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-request

Imagine at a meeting all the participant come to an agreement over something, but there were some other subjects under discussion during the session. The meeting finishes and prior to announcing it, the presenter / meeting leader decides to summarize all the matters and tells and "make a conclusion from all the discussed matters", well. What shall he normally say? Does my sentence bellow make any sense to you:

> Let’s conclude from these matters.

If there is a better way, then please let me know about it.

P.S. I need to use the verb "conclude" or the noun "conclusion" in my sentence.

Added: A university professor in my country can use the same sentence before ending the session.

Comment: I think you just need to take out the word from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the dictionary, you will find that it isn't really appropriate to use the word [conclude](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conclude) in the way that you suggested: it means either **to end a speech, meeting, or piece of writing** or **to judge or decide something after thinking carefully about it**: note that, for the second meaning it must be followed by **that**.

A university professor could say something like this:

> Let's conclude this session by summarizing the points that we have discussed

For a meeting where evidence has been presented and then a judgement made, the second meaning could be used like this:

> We can conclude from the evidence presented that...

[conclusion](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conclusion) can mean **the final part of something** or **the opinion you have after considering all the information about something**. A university professor could use the first meaning like this:

> In conclusion, let's summarize the points that we have discussed

For a meeting where something has been decided, the second meaning could be used like this:

> Let's summarize the conclusions that we have reached in this meeting.

Comment: But based on my dictionary, "conclude" means to extract a result from what has done/said/mentioned/discussed etc. I didn't know that @JavaLatte. Then could you please let me know what should I use in this sense?

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that meaning. Your university professor still couldn't use it to end a session. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

In a formal meeting, the term used to end it is **adjourn**. What would normally be said:

- (possible, if it seems like all business is complete -- chairman) Do I hear a motion to adjourn?
- (any voting member) I move we adjourn.
- (any other voting member) Second!
- (a vote is taken; a motion to adjourn is almost always "in order")
- (chairman, on successful vote) The meeting is adjourned.

([Robert's Rules for Adjourning a Meeting](http://www.dummies.com/careers/business-skills/roberts-rules-for-adjourning-a-meeting/))

Or, in a not so formal meeting:

> Let us adjourn.

Technically, adjournment is a temporary act. But as long as a group exists, it is expected that they will meet again. It may be tomorrow or the first Tuesday of next month, but the group likely has a next scheduled meeting before the call to adjournment was made. A temporary break within a single meeting is called a **recess**.